# browser plugin/addin and page zoom

Tags: plugins, browser, activex, mozilla, add-on

How do mozilla addons or IE activeX plugin's handle browser page zoom ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the size of the window they draw to will be changed by the browser; the NPAPI plugin or ActiveX control just handles the window resize event and does whatever it wants to.  AFAIK there is no real way to detect if it was changed because of the page zoom or by something resizing the object element.

This is from my own experience.